# Why is this query not working for number 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

this query returns 5 results as expected

```
select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 like '0'
```

but this query returns nothing

```
select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 like '1'
```

the USERFIELD1 is a varchar 80 field

Here is all the data that is in the DB and as you can see there are two records with USERFIELD1 = '1' but there seems to be a line break after them...maybe that is causing the issue...is there anyway to grab those two records

```
LEADID,CREATEUSER,CREATEDATE,MODIFYUSER,MODIFYDATE,ACCOUNTMANAGERID,ASSIGNDATE,BUSINESSDESCRIPTION,COMPANY,COMPANY_UC,CREDITRATING,DATAQUALITY,DESCRIPTION,DIVISION,DONOTSOLICIT,EMAIL,EMPLOYEES,FAX,FIRSTNAME,HOMEPHONE,IMPORTID,IMPORTSOURCE,INDUSTRY,INTERESTS,ISPRIMARY,LASTCALLDATE,LASTNAME,LASTNAME_UC,LEADSOURCEID,MIDDLENAME,MOBILE,NEXTCALLDATE,NOTES,PREFERRED_CONTACT,PREFIX,PRIORITY,QUALIFICATION_CATEGORYID,REVENUE,SECCODEID,SICCODE,STATUS,SUFFIX,TICKER,TITLE,TOLLFREE,TYPE,USERFIELD1,USERFIELD2,USERFIELD3,USERFIELD4,USERFIELD5,USERFIELD6,USERFIELD7,USERFIELD8,USERFIELD9,USERFIELD10,WEBADDRESS,WORKPHONE,LEAD_ADDRESSID,DONOTEMAIL,DONOTFAX,DONOTMAIL,DONOTPHONE
Q134915558  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,NULL,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,NULL,Johndoe,JOHNDOE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,test@gmail.com,NULL,NULL,Harry,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Restaurant Pro Express demo download,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,            ,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is from the site,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4075559999,QQ134915558 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q39769667   ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,NULL,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,NULL,scaoo,SCAOO,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,harry333@harry.com,NULL,NULL,upper2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Aldelo for Restaurants demo download,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,L6UJ9A000004,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is a download,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4074615519,QQ39769667  ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q488888476  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,NULL,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,NULL,Johndoe,JOHNDOE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,markus@gmail.com,NULL,NULL,upper,NULL,NULL,NULL,sales,posnation.com online demo request,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,L6UJ9A000004,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is from upper,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4074615519,QQ488888476 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q504845720  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:06:10.053,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:06:10.053,U6UJ9A00000G,2011-09-20 17:06:10.053,NULL,Rafner ext.,RAFNER EXT.,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,raf@raf.com,NULL,NULL,James,4075615519,NULL,NULL,sales,NULL,NULL,NULL,Rafner,RAFNER,            ,NULL,NULL,NULL,Raf associates is asking a question,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,QQ504845720 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q539171226  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,NULL,2011-09-20 17:49:28.963,NULL,scaoo,SCAOO,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,harry333@harry.com,NULL,NULL,upper3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Aldelo for Restaurants demo download,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,L6UJ9A000004,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is a download,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4074615519,QQ539171226 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q547088411  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,NULL,2011-09-20 17:46:18.103,NULL,Johndoe,JOHNDOE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,markus@gmail.com,NULL,NULL,upper,NULL,NULL,NULL,sales,posnation.com online demo request,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,L6UJ9A000004,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is from upper,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4074615519,QQ547088411 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q913526837  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,NULL,2011-09-20 17:36:10.053,NULL,Johndoe,JOHNDOE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,test@gmail.com,NULL,NULL,Parry,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Restaurant Pro Express demo download,T,NULL,Scott,SCOTT,            ,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is from the site agan,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4075559999,QQ913526837 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
Q925684753  ,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-21 09:36:10.420,U6UJ9A00000S,2011-09-21 09:36:10.420,NULL,2011-09-21 09:36:10.420,NULL,POSfasion,POSFASION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,sdfa@ss.com,NULL,NULL,Maria,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Aldelo for Restaurants demo download,T,NULL,becker4,BECKER4,L6UJ9A000004,NULL,NULL,NULL,this is another lead from the live site,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SYST00000001,NULL,New,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,7778889999,QQ925684753 ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: As you say, could be because of new line or other chars - out of interest, what does select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 like '1%' return?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the "LIKE" with "="?  Shouldn't make a difference..but it's something to try

Answer (score 4):

If there are characters after the 1 in the `userField1` then try using a wildcard, as shown below.

```
select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 like '1%'
```

Also the statement you wrote

```
select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 like '1'
```

Is essentially equivalent to

```
select * from [SalesLogix].[sysdba].[LEAD] where USERFIELD1 = '1'
```

You may want to read up on using the [`LIKE` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: `LIKE 1%` will of course match many more things than just `1` + `CrLF`

Comment: @Martin Smith ... That is understood but clearly OP does not understand the functionality of LIKE.  Therefore it would be best to help him understand.  `"Give a man a fish and he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime."`

Comment: My comment adds to that process. No?

Comment: @Martin Smith ... Never said it didn't.  That is what makes this site great.  Many viewpoints allow the OP to think logically about the issue and see where they went wrong.

Comment: Anyway all this talk of eating fish is making me hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 where USERFIELD1 = '1
 '
```

You don't need `LIKE` as you aren't using any wild cards.

Answer (score 1):

- You're using `LIKE` wrong.  Put a wildcard or a pattern in there or use an `=` operator.
- Your data seems malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Try a like with the value surrounded by a wildcard

ie `USERFIELD1 like '1%'`

Should sort out whatever problem you're having if it is related to the line break field